# Notation for difference of sums with different indicies

Tags: summation, notation

I'm looking for a better way to express the following equation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i$$

What would be a cleaner way of expressing this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $n> m$, then

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i=\sum_{i=m+1}^{n} x_i$

If $n=m$, then

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i=0$

If $m>n$,

$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i=-\sum_{i=n+1}^{m} x_i$

Comment: Don't forget the case where $n < m$ which gives $-\sum_{i=n+1}^m x_i$

Comment: @PrimeMover In that case you can replace m with n .

Comment: I edited my answer @PrimeMover to avoid inconvinience.

Comment: Well maybe, but it does not explicitly and unambiguously handle the minus sign. I would recommend that this be thought through once more.

Comment: Yes @prime lover I thought and edited

Comment: I guess that in cases where we don't  know if $n>m$ or $n<m$, then there is no convenient way of expressing this...

Answer (score 1):

Let $k_1=\max{\{m,n\}}$ and $k_2=\min{\{m,n\}}$.

Then,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i=(-1)^{n-m}\cdot \sum_{i=k_2+1}^{k_1} x_i$$

If $m=n$, then of course
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i - \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_i=0$$

Thanks to @Axel for pointing out the $m>n$ case.